# Postgis pgAdmin ST_area returning different to other GIS's

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, database, pgadmin-4

I have a shapefile which is returning a different area value in pgAdmin than in FME, Cadcorp SIS and QGIS and I don't know why it is different in pgAdmin.

The setting used in pgAdmin are:

SELECT ST_Area(GEOMETRY) FROM greenbelt_shp

the shapefile is available at:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AuXPKUoLermKBiEbDrxp9YHIG-58AHQr

Can someone can tell me why it is returning a different value?

[image]

Comment: When a shapefile, which is a specific binary multifile format, is loaded into a database, it is no longer a shapefile. There could be many possible reasons why such a large object is different, including corruption by the loading tool and silent repair by the loading tool. Please [edit] the question to provide more information about the data, including the coordinate system and the number of rings and vertices in the shapefile and the database, and to include the area values only available in the image in the body of your question, as ASCII text.

Comment: To add to what Vince said, I saved your shapefile to GeoJson from QGIS and manually ran a `select ST_Area(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` on the GeoJson geometry,  result was: `56098230.947890095`.  How was the shapefile loaded?

Comment: Hi Jay, this was very useful while working our the cause. The problem appears to be when exporting the Shapefile from Cadcorp sis into pgAdmin, something seems to be wrong with their application and this has been reported.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused when exporting a shapefile from Cadcorp sis into pgAdmin, something appears to go wrong here as when the shapefile is exported from Qgis the area is correct. The bug has been reported to Cadcorp.